# How do I put a nextjs app in maintenance mode (using Vercel)

Tags: next.js, serverless, vercel

I've just released my **nextjs** app to production using **Vercel**.

I'm loving the whole experience except for one tiny part: I would have loved to be able to put my  app in **maintenance mode**, but this option does not seem available on Vercel.

My question is: *Has anyone achieved this before and could share some details here?*

I'm guessing it could be done at 2 levels:

- Modifying my app so that if an environment variable (i.e `MAINTENANCE_MODE=true`) is detected, every page redirects to a maintenance screen. However, this is not ideal, because adding an environment variable on Vercel requires a deployment for it to be taken into account.
- Having a simple per-project toggle to enable/disable maintenance mode from Vercel. That would be mind-blowing.

Comment: What does "maintenance mode" mean?

Comment: Means every page redirects to a static "maintenance" page.

Comment: ✅ You can find a quick and simple solution in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77405578/8730140

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"Maintenance Mode" can be achieved with an Environment Variable and [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) property in your `next.config.js` (requires Next.js 9.5.0 or newer).

```js
module.exports = {
  redirects() {
    return [
      process.env.MAINTENANCE_MODE === "1"
        ? { source: "/((?!maintenance).*)", destination: "/maintenance.html", permanent: false }
        : null,
    ].filter(Boolean);
  }
};
```

This adds a wildcard route that matches incoming requests and then issues a temporary redirect the `/maintenance.html` location.

Note that you **cannot** make changes to a deployment (config or environment variables) without deploying again.

---

#### Old Answer

If you're not using Next.js or using an old version of Next.js, "Maintenance Mode" can be achieved with the [redirects](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/redirects) property in `vercel.json`.

```json
{
  "redirects": [
    { "source": "/((?!maintenance).*)", "destination": "/maintenance.html", "permanent": false }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks a lot! I'll try it asap.

Comment: Where must the maintenance.html file be? I tried putting it at the root of the project, in the `pages` folder and in the `public` folder. Redirection using the `vercel.json` file works great, but the file is not found!

Comment: You could create a file `/public/maintenance.html`. If instead, you want to use `/pages/maintenance.js`, then you would need to modify the "destination" to be `/maintenance ` since the file extension is stripped for pages.

Comment: The issue was not that the file was not found, rather that I had too many redirects, because "/maintenance.html" matches the "/(.*)" pattern, which leads to a redirect, so on.

The solution for me was simply to add one direct by route in my app.

Comment: Ah yes, its stuck in an infinite redirect because every path will match. I updated the `source` property pattern to exclude anything that starts with `maintenance`.

Comment: Does not work if maintenance is a `/pages/maintenance` as `/_next/*` calls are also redirected and prevents loading any static (css/js).

Comment: That's a great anser but if i understand correctly that requires a new "build" of the website which in some cases might take a lot of time ( imagine a continuous deploy situation where tests need to run and a Dockerfile has to be built ) so i think the ideal solution would not be implemented on next.config but instead on all routes using a wrapper? need some investigation.

Comment: I had the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62264995/how-do-i-put-a-nextjs-app-in-maintenance-mode-using-vercel#comment117270894_62310021) as @AtulYadav, which I solved by adding `_next` to the source pattern: `/((?!maintenance|_next).*)`

Comment: For some reason, this syntax doesn't work for me if I use it together with other properties. Even with `.filter(Boolean)` it complains about the null type.

Answer (score 4):

A different solution I am currently using would be to create a separate maintenance page and then conditionally intercept the rendering of the actual component based on an environment variable.

I achieve this by adjusting the _app.js code to:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAINTENANCE_MODE === 'false') {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
  } else {
    return <Maintenance />
}
```

Note that as mentioned in earlier answers, this relies on the Vercel env variables, per their website: "A new Deployment is required for your changes to take effect."

Comment: I read that this can cause search engine crawlers to index your pages with maintenance content.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to comment by **@ptrkcsk**, if you are going the route of putting a maintenance page in `pages` directory and are rendering images with the `<Image>` component from `next/image` you will also want to include your `static` folder to the redirects regex.

This is the source pattern that is working for me: `/((?!maintenance)(?!_next)(?!static).*)`

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, Vercel suggests another way to implement a maintenance mode which does NOT require a re-deployment: [Vercel Example App: Maintenance Page](https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/maintenance-page)

The idea is to use Vercel's [Edge Config](https://vercel.com/docs/storage/edge-config) and [Next.js Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware).

1. Define a key `isInMaintenanceMode` in the Edge Config of your project. Changes to the Edge Config storage are propagated within ~10 seconds (according to Vercel). The downside is that you can not read it from wherever you want. That's why you need step 2. (Further downside: it's [not free](https://vercel.com/docs/storage/edge-config/edge-config-limits).)
2. In your Next.js project create a `middleware.js` file, which checks for the value of `isInMaintenanceMode` and changes the routing accordingly:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { get } from '@vercel/edge-config'

export const config = {
  matcher: '/big-promo',
}

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  // Check Edge Config to see if the maintenance page should be shown
  const isInMaintenanceMode = await get('isInMaintenanceMode')

  // If in maintenance mode, point the url pathname to the maintenance page
  if (isInMaintenanceMode) {
    req.nextUrl.pathname = `/maintenance`

    // Rewrite to the url
    return NextResponse.rewrite(req.nextUrl)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new file called `_app.js` inside the `pages` directory if it doesn't already exist.
2. Add the following code to the file:

```
import React from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const isMaintenance = true; // Set this to false when you're done with maintenance
  const MaintenancePage = () => <div>Maintenance mode</div>;
  
  return (
    <>
      {isMaintenance ? <MaintenancePage /> : <Component {...pageProps} />}
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

3. Customize the `<MaintenancePage>` component as per your requirements.
4. When you want to enable maintenance mode, set `isMaintenance` variable to `true`. When you're done with maintenance, set it back to `false`.
5. Optionally, you can also add some styling for the maintenance page by creating a CSS